Find minimum matching values for equation
I have an array of integers arr say [1, 2, 3, 6, 67]
I have an equation :
a*x+b*y=z, I can use the array values in this equation to replace x and y,  by some array positions say arr[i], arr[j] i and j can be different or same.
so it looks like this:
a*arr[i] + b*arr[j] = z;

Now I have another array Zarr = [1, 4, 30, 7, 88]
The task is to find values for a and b such that a*arr[i] + b*arr[j] = Zarr[k], where k is the index position of Zarr.
once a and b are calculated I need to get the sum (a + b) and store in result, the condition is the sum (a+b) should be minimum.
I have 1 more restriction, if the sum a+b is more than input variable Z_MAX, then set result for that index to be -1;
Example:
so for arr =  [1, 2, 3, 6, 67]
Zarr = [1, 4, 30, 7, 88]
Z_MAX = 5

Result is [1,2,5,2,-1]
Explanation:
Zarr[0] = 1
i=0, j=0
a=1, b=0
sum = a+b = 1
Eq = 1*1 + 0*1 = 1

Zarr[1] = 4
i=1, j=1
a=1, b=1
sum = a+b = 2
Eq = 1*2 + 1*2 = 4

Zarr[2] = 30
i=3, j=3
a=5, b=0
sum = a+b = 5
Eq = 5*6 + 0*6 = 30

Zarr[3] = 7
i=0, j=3
a=1, b=1
sum = a+b = 2
Eq = 1*1 + 1*6 = 7

Zarr[4] = 88
It's not possible to find a and b whose sum to be less than or equal to Z_MAX, so -1

Finally result = [1,2,5,2,-1]

Here is my code, using brute force approach:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = solve(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 6, 67}, new int[]{1, 4, 30, 7, 88}, 5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));//1,2,5,2,-1
}


public static int[] solve(int[] arr, int[] zArr, int Z_MAX) {
    int n = arr.length;
    int[] result = new int[zArr.length];
    for(int i=0; i<zArr.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < zArr.length; p++) {
      int z = zArr[p];
      
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
          for(int j=0; j<n;j++) {
              
              for (int a = 0; a <= Z_MAX; a++) {
                for (int b = 0; b <= Z_MAX; b++) {
                  if (a * arr[i] + b * arr[j] == z) {
                    result[p] = Math.min(result[p], a + b);
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
          }
      }
      if (result[p] > Z_MAX) {
        result[p] = -1;
      }
    }
    return result;
}

Constraints:
array size is of range 1 to 1000
array element values in range 1 to 10^7
Z_MAX is 1 to 20
zArr size is 1 to 20
zArr element values in range 1 to 10^9

What is the correct approach to solve this, How can the time complexity be decreased?

Is z prime (thus is a field)?

@Neil, z need not be a prime.

@maraca, but they should match with the equation

Yes, it is basic math: b = (z - a * arr[i]) / arr[j], no loop needed, use modulo first instead of division to verify it is a solution.

Are you allowed to have a or b be negative? This would allow for solutions like arr=[9,10] and zArr = [5] , z_max = 10 resulting in [0] since we have -5*9 + 5*10 = 5, meaning a + b = -5 + 5 = 0

@wLui155, negatives are not allowed for all values.

Your algorithm is O(n^2 * z_max^2). But with 2 pointers you can bring it down to O(n * z_max^2) assuming arr is ordered already, otherwise it is O(n log n + n * z_max^2).
// expects ordered arr
public static int solve(int[] arr, int z, int Z_MAX) {
    // check special case where a or b is 0
    int res = Z_MAX + 1;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0 && z / arr[i] <= Z_MAX; i--) {
        if (z % arr[i] == 0) {
            res = z / arr[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    // now check other cases in order
    for (int sum = 2; sum < res; sum++) {
        for (int a = 1; a < sum; a++) {
            int b = sum - a;
            int j = arr.length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                // this is the key, the j pointer going left as needed
                while (j >= 0 && a * arr[i] + b * arr[j] > z)
                    j--;
                if (j < 0)
                    break;
                if (a * arr[i] + b * arr[j] == z)
                    return sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return res <= Z_MAX ? res : -1;
}  


Wouldn't this be O(n * z_max^2 * len(zArr)) since solve solves for a single z, and would be applied to each z in zArr?

@wLui155 yes that's right, I omitted that part to make it simpler, because I don't think you can solve all z at once i.e. wouldn't gain anything from it.

Since your answer has been selected I don't see merit in posting a new one but here's an outline for posterity. We may use the fact that a*arr[i] + b*arr[j] = z is equivalent to z - b*arr[j] = a*arr[i] and memoize all a*arr[i] first. Afterwards, for each z, iterate on every b*arr[j], and search if z-b*arr[j] exists in storage ( matches to an a*arr[i]), then select the best (a, b) pairing as the result, if the boundary condition is met. The runtime for finding the optimal (a, b) pair for a single z would then be O(n*z_max)

@wLui155 Good algorithm but it's not better because you store a * arr[i] only once, could do it for each z and still have the same overall complexity.

@wLui155 OP can always change the accepted answer if a better solution is posted...

@wLui155, please share the answer you are referring to, it will help me to understand.
